# FreeRTOS --vTaskDelay makes the processor P4080 halt.

Tags: delay, porting, freertos, powerpc

I am porting FreeRTOS on PowerPC arch processor P4080, basically followed the example port PPC405.

Its all successful, everything is working fine except for `vTaskDelay`.

Whenever there is a a call to `vTaskDelay` the processor gets a halted. The exception is not consistent i.e., sometimes it's Data TLB error, sometimes it's Program Error, and sometime it's just Target Reset. I have tested all other functionalities, they are working fine.

But the amazing thing is, whenever I try to do step-input debugging - I never get any problem,  vTaskDelay works just fine. But I run the program, I get this error.

1. Can anyone tell me where could be the problem?
2. Any other way to debug the issue?

Kindly help me solve it asap. As I am nearing to my master thesis dead line, without this being solved I can't proceed further.

Comment: It sounds like it could be a race condition of sorts between an interrupt and the task, and by debugging in steps you manually resolve it. If I recall, FreeRTOS has a separate delay list for tasks, so you may want to make sure that the code touching the list is properly protected in critical sections.